# Even Odd number using Thread locking system

Tags: java, multithreading

Today I was doing some practice on Thread and was trying to create one Even Odd number program. I created this using synchronized and it was working fine.
But when I tried to do the same thing using Lock then I stuck.

Below is the code that I am trying to do the same.

```
public class OddEvenNumberThreadLock {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    SharedObject sharedObject = new SharedObject();

    Thread evenThread = new Thread(new EvenNumber(sharedObject));
    Thread oddThread = new Thread(new OddNumber(sharedObject));

    evenThread.start();
    oddThread.start();
}

}



 class EvenNumber implements Runnable {
SharedObject object;

public EvenNumber(SharedObject object) {
    this.object = object;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i = i + 2) {

        while (!object.isOdd()) {
            object.getLock().lock();
            try {
                System.out.println("Even : " + i);
                object.setOdd(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                object.getLock().unlock();

            }

        }

    }

}

}
class OddNumber implements Runnable {
SharedObject object;

public OddNumber(SharedObject object) {
    this.object = object;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i = i + 2) {

        while (object.isOdd()) {
            object.getLock().lock();
            try {
                System.out.println("Odd : " + i);
                object.setOdd(false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                object.getLock().unlock();

            }

        }

    }

}
}

class SharedObject {
private Lock lock;
private boolean isOdd;

public SharedObject() {
    this.lock = new ReentrantLock();

}

public boolean isOdd() {
    return isOdd;
}

public void setOdd(boolean isOdd) {
    this.isOdd = isOdd;
}

public Lock getLock() {
    return lock;
}

public void setLock(Lock lock) {
    this.lock = lock;
}
}
```

I have one more question there like in the case of synchronized we use notify method to inform other thread. How we can achieve this thing in case of Lock.

Comment: Your access to isOdd isn't thread safe. As it's a boolean it can be inlined and never actually accessed. note: as you have a potential infinite inner loop, you could iterate any number of times.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but here isOdd is being set inside lock, so why its not thread safe.

Comment: Your writing is thread safe, but your reading is not.

Comment: Thanks again, so in current code, if multi thread access this while(…) condition then, lets say thread A acquire lock then Thread B can not acquire lock. So still read is safe. though not sure. could you please add comment on this.

Comment: There is no reason to believe the read is safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you want to achieve that the two threads of yours print even and odd numbers in a ping-pong style. The behavior you want is easier to achieve with `ReentrantLock` than with `synchronized` block since `synchronized` is always unfair, but you can make `ReentrantLock` to be fair using the aproppriate constructor. Here is how your program would look like with `Lock`s:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        SharedObject sharedObject = new SharedObject();

        Thread evenThread = new Thread(new EvenNumber(sharedObject));
        Thread oddThread = new Thread(new OddNumber(sharedObject));

        evenThread.start();
        oddThread.start();
    }

}


class EvenNumber implements Runnable {
    SharedObject object;

    public EvenNumber(SharedObject object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while(i <= 100) {
            object.getLock().lock();
            try {
                if (!object.isOdd()) {
                    System.out.println("Even : " + i);
                    i = i + 2;
                    object.setOdd(true);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                object.getLock().unlock();

            }
        }
    }
}

class OddNumber implements Runnable {
    SharedObject object;

    public OddNumber(SharedObject object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public void run() {
        int i = 1;
        while(i <= 100) {

            object.getLock().lock();
            try {
                if(object.isOdd()) {
                    System.out.println("Odd : " + i);
                    i = i + 2;
                    object.setOdd(false);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                object.getLock().unlock();

            }

        }

    }
}

class SharedObject {
    private Lock lock;
    private boolean isOdd;

    public SharedObject() {
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    }

    public boolean isOdd() {
        return isOdd;
    }

    public void setOdd(boolean isOdd) {
        this.isOdd = isOdd;
    }

    public Lock getLock() {
        return lock;
    }

    public void setLock(Lock lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Antario, It is working and was really simple.